# What is the English word that means "making something more broadly known and understood"?

Tags: single-word-requests

A company issues a new regulation and **wants to make the new regulation more broadly known and understood  by all of its employees**.

What do we say the company does?  (The company ... its new regulation.)

Is the word "socialize" appropriate to fill the blank above?
I am looking for a word that has the property of "efforts" to ensure the regulation is known by all and understood thoroughly instead of merely making it public, so words like "announce" and "publicize" are not sufficient.

Comment: Not sure what the english word for it is. Billiards is off-topic here. This site is really sort of more like about English, the Germanic language.

Comment: "Promote" or "Advertise" in the sense of  calling attention to (something) or causing people to notice (something).

Comment: Couldn't something like "wide-spreading" be appropriate ?

Comment: (In fact i guess it doesn't as it doesn't really take into account the "understood" part of your question but that was in case you were short of suggestion :)

Comment: :"Broadcast" is one word.  But consulting a thesaurus will get you "announce", "proclaim", "disclose", "declare", "disseminate", "publicize", "promulgate", "publish". "reveal", "notify", "propagate", ad nauseam.

Comment: @mgc "The company wide-spreaded its new regulation"? I can't see that catching on, if I'm honest.

Comment: @JohnClifford you're right, I guess I meant something like: once these regulations have been _<put the appropriate word here>_, we could probably say that they are, for example, widespread regulations ? (anyway I realize, according to the most voted answer that I was just paraphrasing "disseminate" : spread or disperse widely)

Comment: The verb is normally applied to staff in this context: e.g. *training*. For the regulations, you could try to *institutionalise*, with the benefit that if the training effort fails, you can still say it's *been institutionalised*. :)

Comment: You can 'divulge' knowledge, but that generally has a negative connotation since it refers to spreading personal information, not regulations.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

***disseminate*** as defined by [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/disseminate)

> spread or disperse (something, especially information) widely. "health
>   authorities should foster good practice by disseminating information"

In your example:  "The CEO ordered the Human Resources Office to disseminate the new policy on workplace harassment by holding a meeting, with ample time for Q&A, in every division by the end of the quarter."

Comment: Whoever downvoted this post, can you explain why this post doesn't answer the question or how can it be improved?

Comment: @Rathony Thanks.  If I hadn't seen it happen to others, I'd be paranoid.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure which one to upvote: disseminate is a great word, but I can't help but feel that in the OP's sample sentence "The company circulates its new regulation" sounds more natural than "The company disseminates its new regulation". Hell, I'll upvote both. +1!

Comment: The word disseminate is a good word.  It does not belong in that sentence.

Comment: Odd, I think **disseminate** is more natural than **circulate** here. However, **publish** carries an additional sense of making official. In olden days, perhaps **proclaim**.

Answer (score 17):

**Promulgate** could work.

> [Promulgate](https://www.google.com/search?q=promulgate&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) - promote or make widely known 
>   Example: These objectives have to be promulgated within the organization.

Comment: I do not believe *promulgate* is the right word, although its meaning would be clear. It is too portentous to the task in hand, and belongs to things such as religious messages. (There used to be an organisation called *Society for the Promulgation of the Gospel*.) *Disseminate* is a far better option, for getting information out to employees etc. in my view.

Comment: @WS2: on the contrary, I think *promulgate* is the perfect word to use here, since it carries a connotation/side meaning of "put into effect". I don't think it's a portentous word at all.

Answer (score 13):

Another possible word is **popularise**.

From [Cambridge Dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/popularize):

> popularize verb [T] (GENERAL) 
>    - to make something ​known and ​understood by ​ordinary ​people: Television has an ​important ​role to ​play in popularizing new ​scientific ​ideas.

From [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/popularise):

> 2. popularise - make understandable to the general public; "Carl Sagan popularized cosmology in his books"

Answer (score 10):

You could consider using the verb [circulate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/circulate) which means:

> to pass from person to person or place to place

When there was no [intranet](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intranet) (inter-company internet), a memorandum about a new regulation was circulated from a person to another person within a team or department to make sure they understood it well. They had to sign their initials on a signature box after reading it. The word is still being used and the memorandum is circulated in the form of an electronic document on the intranet. If it is classified as confidential or very important, a company still circulates a printed version.

Your example:

> The company circulates its new regulation on the intranet.

[Merriam-Webster]

Answer (score 6):

Not an exact match but ***evangelize*** is sometimes used for *spreading awareness about a technology*, see [Technology evangelist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_evangelist) entry on Wikipedia.

Comment: I think you evangelize people, not regulations.

Comment: @Jacinto you can evangelize software so why not regulations?

Comment: I don't think you can evangelize software. My understanding is that *religious evangelism* means preaching the gospel to people, and converting them to your religion (check [evangelize at M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evangelize). So by analogy, *technology evangelism* means 'preaching' technology to people, and trying to get people to adopt technology. In both case you evangelize people.

Comment: @Jacinto If you want to convert people to your religion, you have to spread the awareness and understanding first, hence the similarity. By ‘evangelizing software’ I meant ‘evangelizing people about software’, my mistake.

Comment: I am most used to *evangelizing <some topic> **to** some people*.

Comment: @Jacinto "Evangelize" literally means to spread good news and all the uses I know of follow that idea. For example, if you are a "free software evangelist" you are spreading the word about its benefits to your listeners. I do not think most employees would see a new set of regulations as good news. I also would hesitate to use "evangelize" as a transitive verb.

Answer (score 5):

I think "promote" is the best option here.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/promote

> 3. To urge the adoption of; advocate: promote a constitutional amendment.
> 4. To attempt to sell or popularize by advertising or publicity: commercials promoting a new product.

Answer (score 1):

It's a neologistic use I don't particularly like, but "socialize" as a transitive verb fits this fairly well if you want to use a word which is business-speaks.

You would use this, for example, by saying "the company will need to socialize these new regulations to make sure everyone is familiar with them."

Comment: Thank you for your input.  Could you please give some examples with the word "socialize" used in this meaning?

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Socializing regulations sounds like altering them in some way to make them fit for society. Can you provide actual examples where the word is used as you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Consider "publish" - the process of production and dissemination of literature, music, or information — the activity of making information available to the general public.

Consider also, "inculcate" - instill (an attitude, idea, or habit) by persistent instruction.

Answer (score -1):

***disclose***, defined by [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/disclose) as:

> to reveal or expose information that has previously been kept a secret
>   — like a politician might be forced to disclose his finances or former
>   scandals while running for office.

Comment: You answer was too laconic for a good answer here.  I edited it to bring it in line with the site's requirements.

Comment: @ab2 I like my answers abridged :(